# Intraprocess zero-copy seems to be working for multiple subscribers

Tags: ros, ros2, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When following instructions from [Pipeline with two image viewers](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Intra-Process-Communication.html#pipeline-with-two-image-viewers), running

```
ros2 run intra_process_demo image_pipeline_with_two_image_view
```

the expected result is that the last pointer in image_view_node_2 has a different memory address.

**However, all the memory addresses are the same.** Does this mean zero-copy intraprocess communication works for multiple subscribers? Or is it my misunderstanding somewhere?

[image: image description]

ps. ROS2 Galactic, DDS is left as default (CycloneDDS)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385938/intraprocess-zero-copy-seems-to-be-working-for-multiple-subscribers/) by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2021-09-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tested this demo with foxy/galactic/humble, and only with humble it will work like your description.
So my best guess is the demo you are using contains this [commit](https://github.com/ros2/demos/commit/d9c8dacaeddbb7fd8316b1e2bd9b04160f8c6a2c), which should only be available since humble.

The [foxy/galactic document](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Demos/Intra-Process-Communication.html#pipeline-with-two-image-viewers) is somehow wrong:

> This means the system deliveres the same shared_ptr to both callbacks. When the first intraprocess subscription is handled, the internally stored unique_ptr is promoted to a shared_ptr. Each of the callbacks will receive shared ownership of the same message.

[The foxy/galactic demo's ImageViewNode callback](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/26e048b88ac16b52523323bb3f193d0b83dabf76/intra_process_demo/include/image_pipeline/image_view_node.hpp#L40) used type `const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::SharedPtr` as argument, and it's **NOT** shared ownership. Then the intra-process logic have to copy the message to make sure each ImageViewNode will have exclusive ownership of the message dispatched to them, which behaves the same as callbacks using type `const std::unique_ptr<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>`.

[The humble demo's ImageViewNode callback](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/f258b8182c7ad680c8cceba38eac72e01fdb0a3c/intra_process_demo/include/image_pipeline/image_view_node.hpp#L44) changed the argument type to `sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr`, and now it really means shared ownership. Then the demo behaves like your description, so the humble's document should be updated to reflect this change.

The intraprocess zero copy for multiple subscriber should always work since foxy, as long as you are using the correct signature for callbacks.

The callback argument type and ownership relationship can be verified using this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/image.hpp>

template<typename TCallback>
void PrintAnyCallbackSharedOrNot(TCallback&& cb) {
  rclcpp::AnySubscriptionCallback<sensor_msgs::msg::Image, std::allocator<void>> acb{std::allocator<void>()};
  acb.set(std::move(cb));
  std::cout << acb.use_take_shared_method() << std::endl;
}

int main(int , char *[]) {
  // false
  PrintAnyCallbackSharedOrNot([](std::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>){});
  // false, same as const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::SharedPtr
  PrintAnyCallbackSharedOrNot([](const std::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>){});

  // true, same as sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr
  PrintAnyCallbackSharedOrNot([](std::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::msg::Image>){});
  // true
  PrintAnyCallbackSharedOrNot([](const std::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::msg::Image>){});
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [tsingakbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/118701/tsingakbar/) with karma: 26 on 2023-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0